# How to contain a image responsively on an amp page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, amp-html

As we need to define an image with amp-img tag for an amp page, the problem is with the responsive nature of those image.
For example:

```
<p align="center"><amp-img width="400px" height="200px" layout="responsive" src="https://xyx.com/abc.png"></p>
```

Now if the master div is 600px then, the image will get stretched out to 600px (more than its normal 100%), but for a  mobile device with master div being 300px , the image will adjust the height and will be perfectly fine as it will get contained in the 300px div stretching it to 100% won't make effect.
Also, layout cannot be set to fixed because it will then stretch out of the mobile display.
What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dynamic width of the image and want to handle this situation than go to this link : https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/how_to_support_images_with_unknown_dimensions/ and read "Fixed-Height Layout with correct Aspect Ratios" section.
It will help you to implement amp-img when you do not know the image width and do not want the image to be get stretched.

Comment: In case someone needs this, the above link is broken, and I think [this is the current replacement link](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/style-layout/how_to_support_images_with_unknown_dimensions/?format=websites).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

**CSS**

```
<style amp-custom>
    .magic-img { max-width:400px; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="magic-img">
   <amp-img width="400" height="200" layout="responsive" src="https://xyx.com/abc.png"/>
</div>
```